# Dynamically add new uniform to a material in ThreeJs?

Tags: three.js, uniform

Is it possible to add a new uniform to a standard MeshMaterial dynamically in ThreeJs?

Something like this:

```
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
material.uniforms = {
  customTexture: new THREE.Texture(canvas),
  textureSize: { value: 1024 },
};
```

I have modified some THREE.ShaderChunks so it is able to use the new uniforms in the shader, but it seems that the new uniforms are ignored by three.js when the material gets compiled...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a new uniform to a standard MeshMaterial dynamically in ThreeJs?

Yes. Please have a look at the following example: [webgl_materials_modified](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_modified.html)

In this demo, `MeshNormalMaterial` is enhanced with an additional uniform `time` and some vertex transformation logic. It uses [Material.onBeforeCompile()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/materials/Material.onBeforeCompile) which is executed immediately before the shader program is compiled. This is the recommended approach for modifying built-in materials in `three.js`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the demo, still usefull in 2024!
Why do we need to use `userData` and can't set it directly in the `material.uniforms`?